# Vscode extension: How to set treeview loading status

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am developing a vscode extension

I hope to actively set the loading status of treeview

[image: img]

I found nothing after reading the document.
What should i do?

Comment: Have you found the answer?